# Getting the ChildNode name and its Value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML in the following format

```
<DBdestination>
    <val1>ANI</val1>
    <val2>DNIS</val2>
    <val3>Date</val3>
    <val4>Time</val4>
    <val5>ConnId</val5>
    <val6>UUID</val6>
    <val7>EmployeeId</val7>
    <val8>AgentDN</val8> 
</DBdestination>
```

I need to obtain the name of the child of `DBdestination` and their values in a list(or something as such) as `val1,val2,val3,val4.....` and in another list `ANI,DNIS......`

I tried

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/RCCM_TOOL/configRCCM.xml");
var units = xdoc.Descendants("DBdestination").Elements().ToArray();
```

But this gives me the whole of the tag as such.

**How can I get my desired results ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close:

```
xdoc.Descendants("DBdestination")
    .Elements()
    .Select(e => Tuple.Create(e.Name.ToString(), e.Value))
    .ToList()
```

That would give you a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`.

One other alternative would be this:

```
...
    .Select(e => Tuple.Create(e.Name, e.Value))
    .ToList()
```

and that would give you a `List<Tuple<XName, string>>`. The nice thing about that is the `XName` can be compared with the name `val1` and not need the `namespace` whereas the `ToString()` will give you the fully-qualified name.

---

To handle the need to support .NET 3.5; let's do it this way:

```
xdoc.Descendants("DBdestination")
    .Elements()
    .Select(e => new
    {
        Name = e.Name,
        Value = e.Value
    })
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Tuple is not being recognized by my IDE. what reference am I missing ?

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn, what version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn, is there a compelling reason you can't upgrade to `4`?

Comment: `Tuple` is .NET 4. Use an anonymous class instead.

Comment: @Romoku, that's a good option if the OP can't upgrade. However, the `Tuple` data structure is perfect for this.

Comment: Instead of Tuple, you can use an anonymous type like this: new { Name = e.Name, Value = e.value }

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn, please see my edit to use an anonymous type.

Comment: Isn't it `Tuple.Create()` and not `new Tuple.Create()` ? The former treats `Create` like a type when it's a method.

Comment: @DGibbs, yeah that was a typo. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/RCCM_TOOL/configRCCM.xml");
            var units = xdoc.Descendants("DBdestination").Elements();
            var tagnames = units.Select(u => u.Name.LocalName).ToArray();
            var values = units.Select(u => u.Value).ToArray();
```

You can go with dictionary if you look to access the values by the element names, like below:

```
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/RCCM_TOOL/configRCCM.xml");
        var units = xdoc.Descendants("DBdestination").Elements();
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var u in units)
        {
            dictionary.Add(u.Name.LocalName, u.Value);
        }
```

Thereafter you can access the values from the dictionary like below:

```
string value1=dictionary["val1"];
```